# Writing a unittest with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a column in my Data-Frame and ]t should have a "Yes" values,
But my Unit-Test code has an error.
Here is my code:

```
data = func("value")
assert all("Yes" in data == True)
```

The error is :

```
'bool' object is not iterable
```

Comment: What is "an error". Please paste the full contents of the error message.

Comment: Errors is : boolean is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to check that one "Yes" string exists in the data variable

```
assert "Yes" in data
```

If you want to use check every element of the list is "Yes"

```
assert all(x == "Yes" for x in data)
```

However, this is for lists, not dataframes. If you have a pandas dataframe

```
assert data['column'].str.contains('Yes')
```

Comment: Thank you, I added .any at end of the third solution and it worked

Answer (score 0):

`all` should take iterable as an argument not boolean that's why you get this error.